Action of Hamiltonian on two-body fermionic wave function
I have a two-body Hamiltonian as ,
$$H= \frac{1}{2m}  \sum _{i=1}^{2}{p_i}^2 + V$$
where notations have their usual meaning,
Since my wave function is periodic, I defined my two particle fermionic wave function to be ,
$$\Psi(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum_{k_1, k_2 = -\infty}^{\infty} c_{k_1} c_{k_2} \left( e^{i k_1 x_1} e^{i k_2 x_2} - e^{i k_2 x_1} e^{i k_1 x_2} \right).$$
I have written this wave function using the slater determinant and using the fact that if a wave function is periodic it can be written as,
$\psi(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k e^{i k x}$
where $c_k$ is the Fourier coefficient.
After I applied the above Hamiltonian on this Wave function kinetic energy is coming out to be zero.
I am expecting it to be ${k_1}^2+{k_2}^2$, please clarify if I am doing something wrong here !

We can't tell you what you're doing wrong without actually seeing the calculation you did. That said, the answer can't be $k_1^2+k_2^2$, because those are the indices in the summation (although the expression will include a sum over expressions involving $k_1$ and $k_2$).  The kinetic energy will also depend on the expansion coefficients $c$ in $\Psi(x,t)$.  If what you're actually looking for is $\langle \hat{T}\rangle$ for just one of the anti-symmetrized basis functions, then you should indeed get $k_1^2+k_2^2$. All of that said, check-my-work questions are generally off-topic here.

One more point: the expansion coefficients in $\Psi(x_1,x_2)$ should be $c_{k_1,k_2}$ not $c_{k_1}c_{k_2}$. The function $\Psi$ is not generally factorizable. Indeed, it's possible that assuming that the expansion coefficients are of the form $c_{k_1}c_{k_2}$ is what's leading to a kinetic energy of zero.

Your proposed wave function is identically zero: $$\Psi(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)-\psi(x_2)\psi(x_1))=0 $$
